# Как конвертировать HTML в строку и добавить ее в элемент?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть строка:

```
var mainContainer = document.getElementById('main');
var containerHTML = "<div class='test'>Hello</div>";
```

Я хочу эту строку добавить в другой элемент именно, как строку, а не как html-элемент.

```
function addStr(str) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('main');
    mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', str);
}
addStr(containerHTML);
```

Но данная операция добавляет строку, как HTML, то есть я вижу только Hello текст. 
Может, как вариант, сделать так?

```
 html = html.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
 html = html.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

Comment: вы хотите именно _добавить_? или заменить то что уже было в _mainContainer_?

Comment: добавить. То что в containerHTML, именно эту строку и именно в виде строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться свойством [*textContent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
document.getElementById('d').textContent += "<div class='test'>Hello</div>";
document.getElementById('d').textContent += "<div class='test'>Hello</div>";
```

```html
<div id='d'></div>
```

Еще вариант: перед добавлением просто экранировать символы html

```js
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

function addStr(str) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('d');
    mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', htmlEscape(str));
}
addStr("<div class='test'>Hello</div>");
addStr("<div class='test'>Hello</div>");
```

```html
<div id='d'></div>
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @KristoferStrong, если вы про _textContent_ то будьте внимательны - он удаляет содержимое которое было раньше как html и вставляет только текстовый элемент

Comment: textContent - работает со всеми браузерами, я так понимаю, что лучше его использовать?

Comment: @KristoferStrong, зависит от задачи - по примеру который вы привели - да, если у вас внутри контейнера должен быть только текст